# How to add data to specific use reference in firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My current iOS requires the user to sign up and log in and once the user logs in there data is presented in the database by their `user.uid` and their email address they signed up with. Once the user has logged in, I want to the user to be able to store data at their specific `user.uid` node. For example, if "User A" is logged in and they enter some type of data, I want the data to be saved just under that user (so each user should contain their own set of data and should not be to access or modify any other users data besides there own). So my question is, what would be the best way to keep track of the logged in user or access the logged in user to store future references in later view controllers outside of just the log in controller? It's a food delivery app, so once a user is logged in, I wanted all future entered data to be saved under that user in the database.

Code for login controller:

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseAuth

 class LogInController: UIViewController {

var ref: DatabaseReference!


@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!


func placeholders() {
    emailField.placeholder = "Enter Email"
    passwordField.placeholder = "Enter Password"
}






@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in




        let userID: String = (user?.uid)!
        let userEmail: String = self.emailField.text!

        self.ref.child("Users/\(userID)").setValue(userEmail)




        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }

        else {
            print("User logged in with UserID of: " + (user?.uid)!)
        }
        })
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "signedIn", sender: self)


}



@IBAction func signoutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("User has logged out...")
   try!  Auth.auth().signOut()
}



@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }

            print("User created with UserId of: " + (user?.uid)!)


    })
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let flavorsVC = segue.destination as? FlavorsController {
        flavorsVC.ref = ref
        let userEmail = emailField.text
        flavorsVC.email = userEmail!

    }
}







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    placeholders()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

}
```

So again, once the user has logged in, I want all data entered to be saved just under that logged in user on following view controllers. For example in the next view controller I have a variable `bookieAmount`, how could I modify my code to where each logged in user has a separate node where their individual `bookieAmount` can be saved to? So far when I try to implement such functionality it just replaces the previous reference and doesn't create a new for that specific user like I want it to.

Code for next view controller:

```
  class FlavorsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var bookieFlavors = ["Chocolate Chip", "Sugar w/o icing", "Sugar w/ icing", "Peanut Butter", "Honey", "Shortbread", "Ginger", "Double Chocolate", "Macadamie Nut", "Oatmeal Raisin", "Snickerdoodle"]
var amount = [Int]()
var bookieTotal = Int()
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var flavorRef: DatabaseReference!
var email = String()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for _ in self.bookieFlavors {
        self.amount.append(0)
    }
    flavorTable.delegate = self
    flavorTable.dataSource = self

    //database references
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    flavorRef = Database.database().reference()



}

func emptyAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button Held, Amount Emptied")
    self.amount[sender.tag] = self.amount[sender.tag] - (self.amount[sender.tag] + 1)
    let cell = self.flavorTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? FlavorTableCell
    cell?.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[sender.tag])"

}


@IBAction func bookieButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.amount[sender.tag] = self.amount[sender.tag] + 1
    let cell = self.flavorTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? FlavorTableCell
    cell?.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[sender.tag])"
   // print(amount[sender.tag])

    self.bookieTotal = amount.reduce(0, +)
    print(bookieTotal)
}




@IBOutlet weak var flavorTable: UITableView!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int    
{
    return bookieFlavors.count

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FlavorTableCell


    //flavor label configuration
    cell.flavorLabel.text = bookieFlavors[indexPath.row]

    //amount configuration
    cell.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[indexPath.row])"
    cell.bookieButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.bookieButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookieButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.bookieButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emptyAmount(_:)), for: .touchDownRepeat)

    return cell

}

@IBAction func registerBookieAmount(_ sender: Any) {
    print(bookieTotal)

    let amount: Int = bookieTotal
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    if ((user) != nil) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to make a request to Firebase server to see if the user is still logged in by this code

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  let ref = Database.database().reference()
  ref.child("users").child(user.uid).child("orders").setValue(["order": orderNumber])
} else {
  // No user is signed in.

}
```

Comment: where you finally get the user data and want to send it to firebase

Comment: How could I then store all following data references for that user under the same original reference? Say if I wanted to reference data from a different view controller or add data somewhere throughout the app, how could i make sure it just adds it to the users already existing reference?

Comment: I suggest looking at firebase so you get the idea of how it works but as a short answer you first check if the user is logged in "Auth.auth().currentUser" and if it returns true then you store it under user's unique reference in database "user.uid". You can also make this an extension of viewcontroller so you can access it from anywhere you want